# Retrieve file from list as nc input

Tags: bash, sort, netcat, head, nc

I'm trying to create a simple script (one liner, actually) that takes the content of the a file, makes it random, and provides the output to `netcat` as the connection destination.

This is what I thought was needed:

```
NCIP=$(sort --random-sort /root/list.csv | head -n 1) | nc -zv -w 2 $NCIP 443
```

My idea is to set the variable NCIP based on the output of `sort` and `head`, and have the `nc` command call it. For some reason, I can't seem to make this work.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to get one random line from a file, you could use `shuf` instead of `sort`.   Both are shipped in the `coreutils` package.   Example: `shuf -n 1 /root/list.csv`

Answer (score 1):

You need either to

```
$ NCIP=$(sort --random-sort /root/list.csv | head -n 1) ; nc -zv -w 2 $NCIP 443
```

or

```
$ sort --random-sort /root/list.csv | head -n 1 | nc -zv -w 2 -p 443
```

Comment: Since you wrote yesterday that this solution worked for you (especially the first one), why not to accept this answer as solution?